# Can GAE restrict my websocket connections?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, websocket, firewall

I use websocket_client python app and the following code -

```
ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
ws.connect("wss://something.synology.me:1111")
ws.send(json.dumps({
    'token': device_token,
    'payload': {'volume': 0.5}

}))
ws.close()
```

Sometimes it works well, sometimes I get the following error -

```
WebSocketAddressException: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

It worked more or less OK yesterday (let's say worked once in two attempts), but doesn't work at all today. I've tried to run the same code with local Google App Engine - it works well.

Is it possible that the GAE server somehow restricts my connections? What should I check?

Upd. further analysis shows that this problem could be caused by this [part of code](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client/blob/2222f2c49d71afd74fcda486e3dfd14399e647af/websocket/_http.py):

```
def _get_addrinfo_list(hostname, port, is_secure, proxy):
    phost, pport, pauth = get_proxy_info(
        hostname, is_secure, proxy.host, proxy.port, proxy.auth, proxy.no_proxy)
    try:
        if not phost:
            addrinfo_list = socket.getaddrinfo(
                hostname, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOL_TCP)
            return addrinfo_list, False, None
        else:
            pport = pport and pport or 80
            addrinfo_list = socket.getaddrinfo(phost, pport, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOL_TCP)
            return addrinfo_list, True, pauth
    except socket.gaierror as e:
        raise WebSocketAddressException(e)
```

i.e. running [socket.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) on GAE may be the problem.

Comment: Is this standard environment and python2.7? Check [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions).

Comment: @EmilGi, yes, this is the standard environment and python 2.7. I've read about the limitations, I am not sure just about 'paid app' - but as I said - sometimes it works, which is strange.

Comment: Working locally but not at deployment can only mean this is some Python2 standard environment limitation. All I can suggest is moving to Python3 as Python2 is no longer supported.

Comment: @EmilGi, thanks for your help. The problem was with the billing - it wasn't enabled. Strange that there is no normal handling of such a situation from GAE side - there could be some better error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the billing - it wasn't enabled, so sockets didn't work properly.